# combine multiple long to wide transformations into one

Tags: r

I need to transform multiple columns from long to wide the steps below is how I currently do it. Is there a way to generalize this to an arbitrary number of columns? In my current use case the aggregation and cast is always over the same variable `var_1` in the code below the best but not necessary solution would allow me to use `var_1` for the `City` cast and `var_2` for the `Month` cast.  I am fine with a `data.table`, `tidyr`or base R solution. Thanks

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)
dat=data.frame(G1=sample(LETTERS[1:3],200,replace=TRUE),
               G2=sample(LETTERS[10:13],200,replace=TRUE),
               G3=sample(LETTERS[16:18],200,replace=TRUE),
               Month=rep(month.name[1:4],50),
               City=rep(c("LA","NYC","Charlotte","Bloomington"),50),
               var_1=sample.int(200,200),var_2=sample.int(200,200))

cityWide=dcast(setDT(dat), G1+G2+G3~ City,value.var="var_1",fill = 0L,fun.aggregate = sum)
monthWide=dcast(setDT(dat), G1+G2+G3~ Month,value.var="var_1",fill = 0L,fun.aggregate = sum)

wideData=cityWide %>% inner_join(monthWide,by=c("G1","G2","G3"))
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this to cast multiple columns to multiple variables?  `tidyr::pivot_wider(dat, names_from = c(Month, City), values_from = c(var_1, var_2), values_fn = sum)` ?

Comment: Yes, this is great!  I had to add a named list in the `values_fn` argument do you want to submit as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` directly to cast multiple columns to multiple variables and supplying  a function in `values_fn`.

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(dat, names_from = c(Month, City), 
                        values_from = c(var_1, var_2), values_fn = sum)
```

and using `data.table`s `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), G1+G2+G3~Month+City, value.var = c('var_1', 'var_2'), 
      fun.aggregate = sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be we could use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(G1, G2, G3, City) %>% 
    mutate(Sum_var1 = sum(var_1, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(G1, G2, G3, Month) %>% 
    mutate(SumMonth_var1 = sum(var_1, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(G1, G2, G3, Month, City, Sum_var1, SumMonth_var1) %>% 
    distinct %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = c(Month, City), values_from = c(Sum_var1, SumMonth_var1))
```